# How to change the color of bottom bar which have the back button

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to change the color of the bottom bar as in the below image for example black with opacity :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add in the main inside `runApp()`

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
  ));
```

but it couldn't accept with opacity